# Is there a way to programmatically change SegmentedControlIOS selected option in React Native?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a SegmentedControlIOS component that toggles between two values (percentage and amount), which determines whether a number entered by the user is a percentage value or an amount.  I define it as follows:

```
<SegmentedControlIOS 
  tintColor={"#425E6A"} 
  values={this.state.optionNames} 
  onValueChange={this.setSelectedOption.bind(this)}
  selectedIndex={0}
/>
```

When the user taps a different button on the same screen that has pre-defined percentages set, it would then make sense for the SegmentedControl to automatically flip over to percent.  However, I don't see any way in the documentation to be able to do that.

There doesn't seem to be a way to tie the selected value/index to a state variable, for example, or programmatically set the selected value/index.  The closest I can see is pre-selecting an index with the selectedIndex prop.  Is this actually possible in React Native?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `selectedIndex` prop with state. You need to make sure to update your state in the `onChange` event to keep it in sync with what the user selected. Then you can just call `setState` with the index you want to select programmatically and it will work!

Here's a small example that does what you want:

```
React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      selectedIndex: 0,
    };
  },
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <SegmentedControlIOS
          values={['One', 'Two']}
          selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
          onChange={(event) => {
            this.setState({selectedIndex: event.nativeEvent.selectedSegmentIndex});
          }}
        />
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
          this.setState({selectedIndex: 1});
        }}>
          <Text>Toggle</Text>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Worked, thanks!  Is there any actual React Native documentation on this?  From what I've read in the docs, selectedIndex is just for setting the pre-selected index.

Comment: I have to admit that the doc for this component is really bad. Not sure why it says that it is only for the pre-selected index, I had to check the source to see if it would work.

We will be working on improving the docs soon and PRs are always welcomed :)

Comment: You mean a PR on the docs?  Didn't see a way to do that.  Your example would be a good one to have on the documentation :)

Comment: Yes, the docs are extracted from the comments in the source, here's the misleading line https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/SegmentedControlIOS/SegmentedControlIOS.ios.js#L46